# multiple users doing form submission with python CGI

Tags: python, cgi

I have a simple cgi script in python collecting a value from form fields  submitted through post. After collecting this, iam dumping these values to a single text file.

Now, when multiple users submit at the same time, how do we go about it?

In C\C++ we use semaphore\mutex\rwlocks etc? Do we have anything similar in python. Also, opening and closing the file multiple times doesnt seem to be a good idea for every user request.

We have our code base for our product in C\C++. I was asked to write a simple cgi script for some reporting purpose and was googling with python and cgi.

Please let me know.

Thanks!
Santhosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of python based servers you could use. Here's one:

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

> Twisted is an event-driven networking engine written in Python and licensed under the open source

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

reactor.listenTCP(1234, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

You probably want to drop the values into a database instead of a text file.

However threading is available and so you can use `lock()` to ensure only one user writes to the file at a time.

http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

> Locks are typically used to synchronize access to a shared resource. For each shared resource, create a Lock object. When you need to access the resource, call acquire to hold the lock (this will wait for the lock to be released, if necessary), and call release to release it

Comment: Thanks all for the information. My point was just to make a report using simple CGI, i thought it has inbuilt libraries to take care of these scenarios. Any ways, iam now moving to some other solution away from this. Thanks again for all your time!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about multiple users, and considering complex solutions like mutexes or semaphores, you should ask yourself why you're planning on using an unsuitable solution like CGI and text files in the first place. Any complexity you're saving by doing this will be more than outweighed by whatever you put in place to allow multiple users.

The right way to do this is to write a simple WSGI app - maybe using something like Flask - which writes to a database, rather than a text file.

Answer (score 0):

The simple (and slow way) is to acquire a lock on the file (in C you'd use flock), write on it and close it. If you think this can be a bottleneck then use a database or something like that.